# Hiding price when it is zero

Tags: javascript, css

So I am using a theme from themeforest for a car listing dealership.  I am trying to hide the price or display another thing such as a call for price button.

Is there a way to do this with javascript or css?

Here is the current sniplet of code:

```
<div class="price">

    <span <?php if ($show_currency_converter) { ?>class="convert"<?php } ?> data-convert="<?php tmm_get_car_price($post_id, 1); ?>">
        <?php tmm_get_car_price($post_id, 1); ?>
    </span>

</div>
```

Basically when the price variable is $0 , I like to not display at all. Or if I have to display something. I like for it to say "call For Price"

Answer (score 2):

If your `tmm_get_car_price` is the function that will get the price, you could do as follows with javascript/jquery:

```
$('span[data-convert="0"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

If `tmm_get_car_price($post_id, 1)` returns `0` use this CSS.

```
span[data-convert="0"] {
    display:none;
}
```

If it returns `$0` use this CSS.

```
span[data-convert="$0"] {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: This works great.. but then what happen when the code is this? <span
    class="cost<?php if ( TMM::get_option( 'show_currency_converter', TMM_APP_CARDEALER_PREFIX ) ) { ?> convert<?php } ?>"
    data-convert="<?php tmm_get_car_price($post->ID, 1); ?>"><?php tmm_get_car_price($post->ID, 1); ?></span>